# Polish citizenship from grandparents

Tags: passports, poland, polish-citizens

I read recently that Poland gives citizenship (and thus passports and EU membership) to children of Polish citizens.

Could this apply to me(/my parents, and then me) if my grandfather was a Polish citizen at the time of WWII, but was sent through the German camp system, and then ended up in Germany, eventually emigrating from there after the war?

This would be helpful to more easily travel to EU countries.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a question about nationality law, not travel

Comment: @CMaster I wasn't sure if it was on topic of not --is there a better site for it?

Comment: Since getting citizenship and passport is more related to long term stay than travel, I would recommend [expatriates.stackexchange.com/](http://expatriates.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Legal perhaps? Expats would be more likley to have experience with it, but unless you have/are planning to move there, not sure if they would consider it on topic either.

Comment: It could be on topic if the OP mentioned that he wanted it to travel to Europe without needing a VISA, not? Its probably the reason,not?

Comment: A side note: be careful of travelling to Poland before resolving this. I have heard of cases where Polish immigration control refused to let people enter or exit because they were Polish citizens but didn't have Polish passports (even though they did not know they were Polish citizens).

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know (and I am not a lawyer) children of Polish citizens are Polish citizens. It should be enough to have only one parent that is Polish to automatically be Polish, and there is no limit on the number of generations born abroad (as is the case with UK nationality for example). However, there might be some special rules (introduced during communism) that have an impact on your case.

The only thing I could suggest is go to your closes Polish embassy and tell them you would like to apply for a Polish passport, because you claim to have Polish citizenship. They should figure out all the legal details for you and clarify your situation.

EDIT: take a look at http://polish-citizenship.eu

Comment: That's interesting, do you have some references to back up the first fact you pointed out ?

Comment: @blackbird57, I can't quote any legally binding sources, but I added a link to my answer.